# mySQL connection error using php codes

Tags: php, mysql, database

*"Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\appraisal\database.php on line 5
No database selected"*

Why does it show most of the time? But when I refresh the page by entering F5, the error will be gone and will show the output correctly. This doesn't really affects the system but it is quite bothering when our users see the error.

I have the codes here.

```
<?php
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db('db_appraisal');
?>
```

Hoping for your response. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `$conn` parameter to the `mysql_select_db` function call

```
<?php
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db('db_appraisal', $conn);
?>
```

Link to [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

If you are writing new PHP code you should really not be using the `mysql_*` extension as it has been deprecated i.e. it will be removed from PHP sometime soon.

Use either the `mysqli_*` extension or the `PDO` one.